# Search should remain in mobile app domain instead of going to api React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering, react-router

I have created a search bar for a mobile app using react.js and it’s also created for desktop api, when I search from mobile app then search result redirects me to desktop api. I want to remain in mobile app when I search from it. It’s base url is baseUrl: 'http://desktop.version.local' but I want to change it to 'http://mobile.version.local', Location.origin can do it, but I don't know how it will be, so anybody have idea how I can do this?

**Here is my Search bar code...**

```js
class SearchBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12 col-xm-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div className="col-md-4 search-top">
            <div className="search-header">
              <form id="search_mini_form" className="navbar-search" action="/searchresults.html" method="get" encType="text-plain">
                <input type="text" className="search" placeholder="Search by item or category" name="q" id="search" autoComplete="off" />
                <button className="search-btn"><span id="icons8-search" className="icons8-search">Search</span><i className="fa  fa-angle-right" /></button>
                <div id="search_autocomplete" className="search-autocomplete" />
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (document.getElementById('search_mini_form')) {
      document.getElementById('search_mini_form').action = window.colemanReact.config.baseUrl + "/searchresults.html";
    }
  }
}
```

`window.colemanReact.config.baseUrl` has desktop version url so I want to change it to mobile version...

Answer (score 0):

its done by adding

> window.location.origin

but when i search it then it redirect to 404 page error on mobile.